# How cuda handle __syncthreads() in kernel?

Tags: cuda

Think i have a block with 1024 size and assume my gpu has 192 cuda cores.
How cuda handle __syncthreads() in kernels when cuda cores size is lower than block size?

```
__global__ void staticReverse(int *d, int n)
{
  __shared__ int s[1024];
  int t = threadIdx.x;
  int tr = n-t-1;
  s[t] = d[t];
  __syncthreads();
  d[t] = s[tr];
}
```

How 'tr' remaining in local memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing a few things.

First of all, GPU having 192 CUDA cores is the *total* core count. Each block however maps to a single *Streaming Multiprocessor* (SM) which may have a lower core count (depending on the GPU generation).

Let us assume that you own a Pascal GPU which has 64 cores per SM and you have 3 
SMs.
A single block maps to a single SM. So you will have 64 cores handling 1024 threads *concurrently*. Such an SM has enough registers to hold all the necessary data for 1024 threads, but it has only 64 cores which quickly swap which threads they are handling.

This way all the local data, e.g. `tr` can remain in memory.

Now, because of this quick swapping and concurrent execution, it may happen -- completely by accident -- that some threads get ahead of others. If you want to ensure that at certain point all threads are at the same spot, you use `__syncthreads()`. All that function does is to instruct the scheduler to properly assign work to the CUDA cores so that they all are at that spot in program at some moment.